# webview go back without closing the app(kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, webview

M app will display a `WebView` but when I go in to other parts of the website (like `cat.html`) then tap back, it closes the app instead of going back to the `index.html` (homepage)

So I wanna know how will this work, like how can go back to the `index.html` without closing the app .

My code:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val webview = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.webview) as WebView
        webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webview.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
        webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/newsfeed/index.html")
        return v
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

You have to handle this case inside `onBackPressed()` method directly in you Activity (not in Fragment).

You handle this situation in many ways, for example via:

- direct use of Fragment object
- Implementing some extra Interface for that
- ViewModel

## If you will use your `WebView` directly inside Activity

You can use something simple like this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        // If possible - go back in WebView
        webView.goBack()
    } else {
        // If NOT possible - just handle going back as always
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Where `webView` is your view inside XML layout file (inflated in `onCreate()` method).

## But when you have `WebView` inside Fragment, you have to:

1) Create new methods in your Fragment, which

- return information "can go back in WebView" or not.
- "say" WebView that should go back

I fixed a little bit your Android flow (using `onCreateView`) and used Kotlin Extension to set properties in `WebView`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    /**
     * New method, allowing as to check "can we go back in WebView or not"
     */
    fun webViewCanGoBack() = webview.canGoBack()

    /**
     * New method, saying WebView that should go back
     */
    fun webViewGoBack() = webview.goBack()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        webview.run {
            settings.run {
                javaScriptEnabled = true
                setAppCacheEnabled(true)
            }

            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
        }
    }
}
```

2) Use new method inside `onBackPressed()` method in your activity.

**Remember, that you are calling this method on exisiting instance of this fragment**, so you have to store it somewhere:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (homeFragment.webViewCanGoBack()) {
        // If possible - go back in WebView
        homeFragment.webViewGoBack()
    } else {
        // If NOT possible - just handle going back as always
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: kind of loss he #2 part

Comment: Do not understand. @Lence is it works for you? How may I help you?

Comment: where should I insert the override fun onBackPressed()

Comment: @Lence Inside your Activity, where you have this Fragment. Activity is handling `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: ok already inserted it in the mainactivity but, the webViewCanGoBack is unresolved reference

Comment: Here, as example I assed those methods inside `HomeFragment`. DId you add this method inside your fragment? Are you sure that you are calling those method on instance of `HomeFragment`?

Comment: I added he 1st code in the HomeFragment, then the 2nd one in MainActivity

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling this on instance of `HomeFragment`? May there are any problems with visibility? Would you add code of that Activitiy to your question?

Comment: cant send it bud , it doesn't allow very long codes

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RNSR3VdTNvC28m0WpImoLsJgbBF6zMocomJVbRIPR64/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Lence In this code on Google Drive there is NO method `onBackPressed()` and you are not creating Fragments here. Is this correct Activity?

Comment: sir there is no HomeActivity in myappliation it uses HomeFragment.kt for the activity_home.xml